# Error de "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:" exportando datos sqlserver a postgresql

Tags: java, sql-server, postgresql

usando el importador de postgresql 9.4.6 el Migartion Toolkit v49.0.4-2
se uso este comando

```
runMTK.bat -sourcedbtype sqlserver -targetdbtype postgres -allTables -targetSchema public dbo
```

y por falta de varios archivos .jar da error de :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Comment: Saludos JOL, bienvenid@ a SOes, te parece si agregas mayores detalles por favor? http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour y http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask para que te familiarices con el sitio.

Answer (score 2):

1. Descargar el jdk-8u101-windows-i586.exe e instalarlo y debe quedar en la siguiente ruta: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_101\`.
2. Descargar el `jtds-1.3.1-dist`, extraer el archivo `jtds-1.3.1.jar` 
   y colocarlo en `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_101\lib\ext`.
3. Descargar `postgresql-9.4.1210.jre6.jar` y colocarlo en `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_101\lib\ext`.
4. Descargar `pg74.216.jdbc2.jar` de 
   [el sitio oficial](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html)
   y colocarlo en `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_101\lib\ext`.
5. configurar las **variables de entorno** de Java. Puedes ver cómo hacerlo [aquí](http://aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=389:configurar-java-en-windows-variables-de-entorno-javahome-y-path-cu00610b&catid=68:curso-aprender-programacion-java-desde-cero&Itemid=188).
6. Crear una base de datos en PostgreSQL y definir un usuario (login rol) con privilegios preferiblemente de `root`. Yo creé el usuario `dbo` con privelegios `root` y luego creé la base de datos `importarDat` y le indique que el dueño es `dbo`.
7. Cambiar el archivo `toolkit.properties` que está en `C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgresPlus\edbmtk\etc`. Colocar lo siguiente:

   ```
   SRC_DB_URL=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://DireccionIPservidorsqlserevr:Puertousado/Nombre    BaseDatos de sqlserver
   SRC_DB_USER=usuario de sqlserver
   SRC_DB_PASSWORD=contraseña del usuario sqlserver

   TARGET_DB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://direccion ip del servidor postgresql o localhost:puertousado/nombre de la base de datos  postgresql donde se importaran los datos

   TARGET_DB_USER=usuario de la base de datos postgresql
   TARGET_DB_PASSWORD=usuario de la base de datos postgresql
   ```

   **Ejemplo**

   ```
   SRC_DB_URL=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.180.90.25:1433/Ventas
   SRC_DB_USER=sa
   SRC_DB_PASSWORD=csfr4$1

   TARGET_DB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/VentasImp

   TARGET_DB_USER=dbo
   TARGET_DB_PASSWORD=ljgt5*1
   ```

Y listo. Suerte y éxitos.

Comment: Hola @JOL, bienvenido. Cuando escribas una respuesta trata de que esté bien escrita (ortografía y gramática) para que sea entendible. Así mismo, si colocas código, formatéalo con el **signo de las llaves** en el editor. El texto que escribes aquí se llama Markdown y puedes ver una guía [aquí](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet).